# Controller is not called when navigate back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm using angularJS and Jade for my development. I had AppController attach onto my body tag. Each time I visit a new page, the controller will be called. Currently, I have two different layouts. One has a header, navigation, and footer. The other only sidebar. When I visit the first layout and second layout, AppController called. But when I navigate back from the second layout to the first. The AppController is not called.

**index.jade**

```
extends layout/layout
block content
```

**Layout.jade**

```
html
 head
  // some metas and links
 body(ng-app="myApp", ng-controller="AppController")
  div(ng-show="!profile")
   include header
   include sidemenu
   include mainmenu

  div(ng-show="profile", id="Profile", style="display:none;")
   include profile/sidemenu

  div(ng-cloak, ng-view)
     block content

  div(ng-show="!profile")
   include footer

  div(ng-show="profile", id="Profile", style="display:none")
    include profile/scripts
```

**AppController**

```
// When navigating to /profile it will call the second layout
// Otherwise first layout.

if($location.path().split('/')[1] == "profile") {
    angular.element('#Profile').css('display','block');
    $scope.profile = true;
}else{
    angular.element('#Profile').css('display','none');
    $scope.profile = false;
}
```

**Problem**

> When I navigate back to first layout from second layout. The sidebar(which is second layout) overlay with the first layout. The reason is the AppController is not called, hence the css display not called.

Comment: post the second layout

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is wrap the controller code around a function and call that function from both of the layers using `ng-init` directive

```
$scope.cssFunc = function(){

    if($location.path().split('/')[1] == "profile") {
        angular.element('#Profile').css('display','block');
        $scope.profile = true;
    }else{
        angular.element('#Profile').css('display','none');
        $scope.profile = false;
    }

}
```